# Prove that $x\mathbf A y\mathbf B = xy \mathbf A \mathbf B$ where $x$,$y$ are constants and $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I am new to linear algebra, and I'm trying to get my mind around matrix algebra by proving basic propositions. The one that I would like to prove now is following:

> Let $x,y$ be real numbers, and $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ matrices
>   such that multiplication $\mathbf A \mathbf B$ is valid. Prove that
>   $(x\mathbf A )(y\mathbf B) = (xy) \mathbf A \mathbf B$

My attempt:

Let's consider arbitrary entry of the matrix $(x\mathbf A )(y\mathbf B)$, namely $\bigl((x\mathbf A )(y\mathbf B)\bigr)_{i,j}:$

$$\bigl((x\mathbf A )(y\mathbf B)\bigr)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^n (x\cdot a_{i,k})(y\cdot b_{k,j})$$

Applying algebra of the real numbers, we get:

$$\bigl((x\mathbf A )(y\mathbf B)\bigr)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^n (xy)( a_{i,k}b_{k,j}) = (xy) \sum_{k=1}^n ( a_{i,k}b_{k,j})$$

Which can be rewritten as

$$\bigl((x\mathbf A )(y\mathbf B)\bigr)_{i,j} = (xy)(\mathbf A \mathbf B)_{i,j}$$

Since arbitrary entry was considered, we conclude that $(x\mathbf A )(y\mathbf B) = (xy) \mathbf A \mathbf B$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, looks fine to me